# Entity Framework Core - problem with get relationship many to many

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an issue with my Get method. In my `BookRepository` I have this method:

```
public Book GetBook(int id)
{
    return _context.Books
                   .Include(a => a.BookAuthors)
                   .Single(b => b.Id == id);
}
```

These are my 3 classes:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
    public string PublishingHouse { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int ISBN { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}

public class BookAuthor
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

I want display details book on the screen, but when I executed method `GetBook`, I have get something weird -model where is a `Book`, which includes `BookAuthors`, which includes... Book! And again, and again...

[image]

Edit: `AuthorId` is ok, but Author is null - why?

And I don't have any idea how I can display `Authors` in the view? By foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only included BookAuthor. You didn't include Author.

Change your GetBook to

```
public Book GetBook(int id)
{
    return _context.Books
                   .Include(a => a.BookAuthors)
                   .Include("BookAuthor.Author")
                   .Single(b => b.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: it works! Thanks. But can u tell my why I should use .Include("BookAuthor.Author") instead .Include(a => a.Author)? Why I have to pass string?

Comment: You cannot use include(a => a.BookAuthor.Author) for 3rd level table and onwards as BookAuthor is list. Only string can work. You can try ThenInclude(a => a.Author), not sure if it works. I haven't use ThenInclude() yet. If this solved your issue, can mark this as answer. Thanks.