# How to pass model with list from view to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have a problem. I have model:

```
    public class BookViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And I have entity Book class:

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookAuthor> Authors { get; set; }
    public string PublishingHouse { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int ISBN { get; set; }
    public Book()
    {
        Authors = new Collection<BookAuthor>();
    }
```

I want pass list of authors to my controller, but I don't know - how? Below is my view. I want give users possibility of adding new records as dropdown with collection my Authors (from database). For now I am trying adding new input records... But I don't know it will be fine. I am not sure but think my model view is bad.

```
@model Application.ViewModels.BookViewModel
<form>
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Book.Title">Tytuł książki</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Book.Title">
        <label asp-for="Book.PublishingHouse">Wydawnictwo</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Book.PublishingHouse">
        <label asp-for="Book.ISBN">Numer ISBN</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Book.ISBN">
        <label asp-for="Book.NumberOfPages">Liczba stron</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Book.NumberOfPages">
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addAuthor">Dodaj autora</button>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj książkę</button>
</form>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        var i = 0;
        $("#addAuthor").click(function (e) {
            i++;
            var name = '<div class="form-group row"><input name = "Book.Author['+i+'].FirstName" id='+i+' type="text"/><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeSubcategory">Usuń</button></div>';
            $("#addAuthor").before(name);
        });
        $("#container").on('click', '#removeAuthor', function (e) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide all the class structure, I refer to your [previous case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63659382/entity-framework-core-problem-with-get-relationship-many-to-many) and used these classes for testing.

Please be aware that, to pass a list model to action, **its name index must start from `0` and increase sequentially**.

```
  public class BookViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BookAuthor> Authors { get; set; }
        public string PublishingHouse { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
        public int ISBN { get; set; }
        public Book()
        {
            Authors = new Collection<BookAuthor>();
        }
    }
    public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookAuthor
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model Application.ViewModels.BookViewModel

<form asp-action="Add" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Book.Title">Tytuł książki</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Book.Title">
        <label asp-for="Book.PublishingHouse">Wydawnictwo</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Book.PublishingHouse">
        <label asp-for="Book.ISBN">Numer ISBN</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Book.ISBN">
        <label asp-for="Book.NumberOfPages">Liczba stron</label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Book.NumberOfPages">
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addAuthor">Dodaj autora</button>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj książkę</button>
</form>

@section Scripts{

    <script>
        var i = 0
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $("#addAuthor").click(function (e) {
                var name = '<div class="form-group row"><input name = "Book.Authors[' + i + '].Author.FirstName" removeTag="reindex" id=' + i + ' type="text"/><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeSubcategory" onclick="RemoveAuthor(this)">Usuń</button></div>';
                $("#addAuthor").before(name);
                i++;
            }); 
        });
        function RemoveAuthor(da) {
            $(da).parent('div').remove();
            i = 0;
            $("input[removeTag='reindex']").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("name", "Book.Authors[" + i + "].Author.FirstName");
                $(this).attr("id", i);
                i++;
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
  public IActionResult Add(BookViewModel bookViewModel)
        {

            return View();
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: thanks! But how can I build dropdown with existing authors? And next pass ids to controller which user marked?

Comment: @Krispekowy, can you provide your current controller code? And you said pass ids to the controller, what does the ids represent? And is it passed to the controller together with the authors added above? And in which field in the BookViewModel is it received?

Comment: I think my problem is lack of separation... My Book class is my entity class (code first EF), and my BookViewModel reference to Book directly for example "public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }" I will try separate these and come back here with answer what next.